# Orbiting clock visible with the naked eye

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit, earth

Does anyone remember from the 1980s or possibly early '90s in the UK news a (serious) story about contructing a huge orbiting clock so that people would be able to look up at the sky to read the time as visible from the ground with the naked eye?  I seem to remember Patrick Moore voicing his disgust about this and the whole thing was canned.  I remember seeing an artist's impression of how the clock would look in the sky. I cannot find any articles or even just written anecdotes about this.  Was this a spoof or a serious proposition?  Does anyone know which angency proposed this e.g. NASA, ESA, etc?

Comment: Considering that the viewer would have to correct for their time zone, such a device doesn't seem useful.

Comment: After a solar storm, does it blink 12:00?

Comment: @DrSheldon To be fair, not every proposed satellite installation has been strictly utilitarian, but I have my doubts about the seriousness of this one.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egjch.png for context: https://youtu.be/tJj9nvk0AgY?t=155

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1575232 may or may not be helpful

Comment: Googling `"eiffel tower in space" entries` (as quoted) yields 9 results-- apparently this was an attempt to put some sort of art into space.